# Angular Reactive Forms - Push FormGroup into FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I have a `FormArray` which will contain some price adjustment rules. Each rule will contain a `FormGroup` and each `FormGroup` with 4 `FormControl`s. When I am trying to push the `FormGroup` into the `FormArray` getting this error:

> Argument of type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

```
public rules = new FormArray([]);
```

```
private getRuleFormGroup(): FormGroup {
   return this._formBuilder.group({
    from: new FormControl('', {
       nonNullable: true,
       validators: [Validators.required]
    }),
    to: new FormControl('', {
       nonNullable: true,
       validators: [Validators.required]
    }),
    increaseBy: new FormControl('', {
       nonNullable: true,
       validators: [Validators.required]
    }),
    increaseType: new FormControl('', {
       nonNullable: true,
       validators: [Validators.required]
    })
   });
}
```

```
private addNewRule(): void {
   const group = this.getRuleFormGroup();
   this.rules.push(group); //Getting error here
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in console or in CLI?

Comment: Try providing the generic argument: public rules = new FormArray<FormGroup<any>>([])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
this.rules.controls.push(group);
```

Just as FormGroups organize themselves into controls, FormArrays also do, each control being either a FormGroup or a loose FormControl.

Answer (score 1):

You get the mentioned error as [reactive forms are strictly typed by default from Angular 14](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#typed-forms).

To solve the compiler error:

1. Create a type for the `FormGroup`.
2. Specify the `rules` type as `FormArray<FormGroup<RuleForm>>`.
3. Modify `getRuleFormGroup` signature to return the type of `FormGroup<RuleForm>`.

```
interface RuleForm {
  from: FormControl<string>;
  to: FormControl<string>;
  increaseBy: FormControl<string>;
  increaseType: FormControl<string>;
}
```

```
public rules: FormArray<FormGroup<RuleForm>> = new FormArray<
    FormGroup<RuleForm>
  >([]);

private getRuleFormGroup(): FormGroup<RuleForm> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Both the answers are working.. I am marking @GheistLycis answer as correct.